# Ebay MIP upload *.csv error "Item.Country missing"

Tags: api, csv, ftp

currently I am trying to upload articles to ebay with https://developer.ebay.com/products/mip  but getting a result file back where for each article the error appears:

No <Item.Country> exists or <Item.Country> is specified as an empty tag in the request.

Every required field shown here https://developer.ebay.com/devzone/merchant-products/mipng/user-guide-en/default.html#definitions-combined-feed.html?TocPath=Inventory%2520management%257CFeed%2520definitions%257C_____5 is present and also the "Localized For" field.

Does someone have a clue what I miss to make it work?

This is the problematic CSV:

```
SKU,Return Policy,Payment Policy,Shipping Policy,Category,Channel ID,Fulfillment Type,List Price,Location ID,Picture URL 1,Condition,EAN,Product Description,Title,Localized For,Total Ship to Home Quantity,VATPercent,Best Offer Enabled,BO Auto Accept Price,BO Auto Decline Price,Country
1011689,Return Policy - Test Text,Payment Policy - Test Text,Shipping Policy - TestText,,EBAY_DE,SHIP_TO_HOME,10,75172 Pforzheim,https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1b/EBay_logo.svg/1000px-EBay_logo.svg.png,NEW,4008153740657,Really long description,Title of article,de_DE,10,19,true,10,5,DE
```

and this the response csv:

```
SKU, Group ID, Locale, Channel ID, Item ID, Status, Message Type, Message ID, Message
1011689,,de_DE,EBAY_DE,,FAILED,ERROR,10009,No <Item.Country> exists or <Item.Country> is specified as an empty tag in the request.
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing your upload data, but maybe there is a comma or quote missing somewhere in the file? That can cause the columns data to 'shift' so to speak. Another possibility is that there is a carriage return in a text field, or it's not properly terminated by a quote or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will edit my post and add the example which is failing.

Answer (score 2):

The Problem was that on the Merchant Platform Frontend no Store Location was set.

Also policies have to be created before.